# Youtube API PHP upload limit exceeded

Tags: php, api, youtube, cron, exceed

I am using cron job to upload videos from server to youtube channel.

i am getting this error

Caught Google service Exception 400 message is

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.video",
    "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded",
    "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload."
 }
}
```

in google console it is showing quota as 20,871 / 50,000,000

i have quota , but videos are not uploading.

one video is uploading per 15 min. i have to upload 200 videos to my account, but this rate it takes some days to upload.

anyone have solutions for this?

Comment: probably you exceeded the number of uploads

Comment: That quota is probably for all API calls, not uploads alone. I can't see google allowing 50 million uploads per account per day.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quota set by the YouTube API for users. It means that you have hit your upload limit for the day on their platform. The YouTube API works differently to the other Google APIs and you can find out more details here about quotas for [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#calculating-quota-usage).

You are therefore able to carry out the following each day:

> 200,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.
>
> 10,000 write operations and 90,000 additional read operations that
>   each retrieve two resource parts.
>
> **400 video uploads, 1500 write operations, and 50,000 read operations that each retrieve two resource parts.**

The quote should reset at midnight on West Coast US time.

Comment: i have uploaded only 10 videos and showing "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload"

Comment: Are you doing anything else in your script that maybe hitting the API also before doing the upload that maybe consuming quota.